# Error method getString undefind in arraylist<entry> (hashmap)

Tags: android, hashmap

Now i use hashmap to add value from SQLite to show inListview but it's error when i

```
map.put("item_title", friends.getString("nickname"));
map.put("item_fname", friends.getString("fname"));
map.put("item_lname", friends.getString("lname"));
```

error tell me "method getString is undefind in friendEntry"

This is my code in friendEntry

```
package com.example.sqlite.entry;
public class FriendEntry {
private int id;
private String fname;
private String lname;
private String nickname;
public int getId() {
  return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
  this.id = id;
}
public String getFname() {
  return fname;
}
public void setFname(String fname) {
  this.fname = fname;
}
public String getLname() {
  return lname;
}
public void setLname(String lname) {
  this.lname = lname;
}
public String getNickname() {
  return nickname;
}
public void setNickname(String nickname) {
  this.nickname = nickname;
}

}
```

FriendsListActivity

```
package com.example.sqlite;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.sqlite.db.FriendsDB;
import com.example.sqlite.entry.FriendEntry;
public class FriendsListActivity extends Activity {
private Context context;
private FriendsDB db;
private ArrayList<FriendEntry> friends;
private ArrayList<String> data;
private TextView hellotext;
private ListView hellolistview;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.friendlist_layout);

}
public void showAllList(){
    //view matching
    hellotext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hellotext);
    hellolistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.hellolistview);
    //select data
    friends = db.selectAll();
        if(friends.size()==0){
            Toast.makeText(context,"You dont have any friend.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{

            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            HashMap<String, String> map;
            for (int i = 1;i<=friends.size();i++){
            // set value for data   
                map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("item_title", friends.getNickname());
                map.put("item_fname", friends.getFname());
                map.put("item_lname", friends.getLname());
                MyArrList.add(map);
            }
            //adapter
            hellolistview.setAdapter(new adapter());
        }
    }

private class adapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Holder holder;
    @Override

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return friends.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        //create
        if( view == null){
            view = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout,null);
            holder = new Holder();
            holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (Holder) view.getTag();
        }

        //assign data / wait for data 
        holder.title.setText(data.get(position));

        return view;
    }

    private class Holder{
        public TextView title;
    }
}


}
```

This is my FriendsDB

```
 package com.example.sqlite.db;

 import java.util.ArrayList;

 import com.example.sqlite.entry.FriendEntry;

 import android.content.ContentValues;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

 //ใช้ในการ inert update delete
 public class FriendsDB {
 private FriendsDBHelper helper;
 private SQLiteDatabase db;

 public FriendsDB(Context context){
    helper = new FriendsDBHelper(context);
    db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
}
//insert
    public long insert(String fname,String lname,String nickname){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(FriendsDBHelper.TABLE_KEY_FNAME, fname);
        values.put(FriendsDBHelper.TABLE_KEY_LNAME, lname);
        values.put(FriendsDBHelper.TABLE_KEY_NICKNAME, nickname);
        return db.insert(FriendsDBHelper.TABLE_NAME, null ,values);

    }
//select all
    public ArrayList<FriendEntry> selectAll(){
        ArrayList<FriendEntry> friends = new ArrayList<FriendEntry>();
        //     cursor คือ ชุดข้อมูล
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT*FROM"+FriendsDBHelper.TABLE_NAME+"WHERE id != ?",new String[]{Integer.toString(0)});
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.getCount()!=0){
            do{
                FriendEntry friend = new FriendEntry();
                friend.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(FriendsDBHelper.TABLE_KEY_ID)));
                friend.setFname(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FriendsDBHelper.TABLE_KEY_FNAME)));
                friend.setLname(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FriendsDBHelper.TABLE_KEY_LNAME)));
                friend.setNickname(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FriendsDBHelper.TABLE_KEY_NICKNAME)));
                friends.add(friend);

            }while(cursor.moveToNext());

        }

        return friends;
    }
```

Comment: As points out in the answers, your class does not feature a method `getString`. Did you mean to call `toString` as inherited from `Object`. If you did, beware that the method might not output what you expect if you don't override it. Without your own implementation, it will likely only print the instance reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use like this**

```
for (int i = 1;i<=friends.size();i++){
            // set value for data   
                map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("item_title", friends.get(i).getNickname());
                map.put("item_fname", friends.get(i).getFname());
                map.put("item_lname", friends.get(i).getLname());
                MyArrList.add(map);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
map.put("item_title", friends.getNickname());
```

Because you have created with Getter setter method... And you can also get similar for others..

Comment: It's still error (the method getNickname()is undefind for the type ArrayList<friendEntry>)

Comment: this is the problem because you are adding to it ArrayList of String and then you are getting the Size of your friends list in getCount method.. So there is two options...1) The data in which you are inserted in ArrayList<STring>, pass this list to your adpater 2) Make another arraylist for friendEntry class and pass to that list to your adapter.

Comment: How can i do if i want to use ArrayList from friendEntry

Comment: i get all friend by db.selectall and put it in friends .Now i want to get value(fname,lname,nickname) in array friends to put it in map

Answer (score 0):

Your Friends class does not a method called `getString(string)`

Use this

```
map.put("item_title", friends.get(i).getNickname());
map.put("item_fname", friends.get(i).getFname());
map.put("item_lname", friends.get(i).getLname());
```

To set a nickname you need to call `friends.setNickname("name")` coz you have the below

```
    public void setNickname(String nickname) {
    this.nickname = nickname;
    }
```

Edit: I also see you have this `showAllList()` but you do not call it any where in your activity class. Call `showAllList()` after `setContentView(R.layout.friendlist_layout)`.

You probably need to do this  `db = new FriendsDB(ActivityName.this)` before doing  `friends = db.selectAll()`.

Comment: Thank you very much ,Yes i missing

Comment: @ThanapoomNaNakhon you are missing some code as suggested in the edit

Comment: @ThanapoomNaNakhon as you see the comments here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18353974/runtime-error-when-activity-startactivity-about-listview. i already mentioned about initializing db here in the dit section